# Limiting output to hundredths place with console.writeline() in c#

Tags: c#, rounding

I've seen similar posts on this, but I can't find a thread that makes sense of this problem to me. This is a second-week project I was working on for class. I'm wanting to limit the output of subtotal. total tax, and grand total to the hundredths place once the calculations are done. But I can't figure out how I need to modify my existing console.writeline() statements.

```
using System;

namespace Week_2_CIS_Lab_Assignment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declare Variables
            double itemOne = 0;
            double itemTwo = 0;
            double itemThree = 0;
            double itemFour = 0;
            double subTotal = 0;
            const double taxTotal = 0.07;
            double grandTotal = 0;

            //Get the values from the user
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the total value of the first time: ");
            itemOne = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the total value of the second item: ");
            itemTwo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the total value of the third item: ");
            itemThree = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of the fourth item: ");
            itemFour = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            //internal stuffz
            subTotal = itemOne + itemTwo + itemThree + itemFour;
            grandTotal = subTotal + (subTotal * taxTotal);

            //Output results
            Console.WriteLine("Your subtotal is: $" + subTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Your total tax is: $" + taxTotal * subTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Your grand total is: $" + grandTotal);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate anyone's input on this. Regards!

Comment: Check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: For a start, you should be using the `decimal` type instead of `double` for monetary values.

Comment: Andrew is correct. *Always use decimal for money*.  Use double for physical quantities like mass or speed.  If your class is not teaching you that then *correct the professor*. This is really important; we designed the decimal type for a reason. Doubles are really bad at representing decimal quantities.

Comment: Next, do not use `Convert.ToWhatever` to convert a *user input* string, because the user might input an invalid string, and you haven't detected that. Your program will crash if they do. Instead, use the `TryParse` methods, and handle the case where they return false. Likely you'll want to write a loop, and put it in a method of its own.'

Comment: Next, `taxTotal` is not correctly named, since it is not a *total* of any sum.  It's a *rate*, so name it accordingly.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for the information. I see what you're saying. After reviewing my course material, I see that the instructor did actually show us to use decimals when dealing with currencies. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @EricLippert I appreciate the help. I noticed that I was, in fact, able to enter other data types as you had suggested could be an issue. I'm working on correcting this. The assignment is already over with but I want to finish this assignment completely. I'll post my results once I've updated it. Thanks again!

Comment: The documentation which Vladislav kindly linked to shows the "C" format string for currency. It will even add the currency symbol for you and take care of thousands separators.

Answer (score 0):

Using string interpolation:

```
double d = 1.23;
Console.WriteLine($"{d:F2}");
```

or with String.Format

```
Decimal d = 1.23M;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:F2}", d));
```

The is "fixed" format (Fn) specified the number of digits after the decimal, F1 for 1 digit, F2 for 2 digits, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It took me a few minutes of messing around with it but I was able to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

```
            Console.WriteLine("Your total tax is: $" + totalTax.ToString("F2"));
        Console.WriteLine("Your grand total is: $" + grandTotal.ToString("F2"));
```

Seems to do the trick! Thanks!

Comment: If you found a particular answer helpful, upvote it and then hit the checkmark to accept the answer.